# Intuition of Homotopy

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, algebraic-topology

The definition of a homotopy is the following. Let $f,g:X \to Y$ be continuous between topological spaces. A homotopy is a function $H:X \times [0,1] \to Y$ that satisfies:
$(i)$ $H$ is continuous. $(ii)$ $H(x,0)=f(x)$, $H(x,1)=g(x)$ for all $x \in X$.

The usual intution is that one pictures two (potentially not straight) lines $f,g$ and views $H$ as a time process that deforms $f$ to $g$. I understand the picture in this intuition, but I wonder why it works. A usual picture for a special case, namely when $f,g$ are paths with common start and endpoints is given by the following picture from hatcher's algebraic topology on page 25.[image]

Why does this picture match the definition? Firstly, what is actually shown here? It shows the image (or parts of the image rather) of $H$, where it is shown that $H(x,1)=f_1(x)$ and $H(x,0)=f_0(x)$ for all $x$. Therefore this part of the definition is matched. However, how can one see that this is continuous? I know that one would probably say something like "it indicates a continuous motion" but that seems rather circular. I was wondering if there is a more formal way to see this, since I usually try to doubt pictures and feel like it is useful to question intuition.

Comment: It is just a figure; it captures the idea of what is going on very well. It would be impossible for an image to display the entire continuum of $H(x,t)$ after all

Comment: As for what exactly is shown there: $f_0$, $f_{1/9}$, $f_{2/9}$, $f_{3/9}$, ...., $f_{8/9}$, and $f_1$.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might have the flow of ideas backwards. There's no way to make this picture "rigorous" or "formal" because, for instance, no equations describing the lines or the homotopies are given. However, the definition of continuous was chosen because it makes precise our intuition for pictures like this!

Let's start with what's "actually shown here". We have two paths, $f_0$ and $f_1$, drawn in bold. Then we have $8$ intermediate paths drawn between them. We might think of these as being pictures of $f_{k/9}$ as $k$ goes from $1$ to $8$ (and obviously $f_0$ and $f_1$ are the cases $k=0,9$ respectively).

Informally, it's clear that these paths *continuously* move from $f_0$ to $f_1$, because wiggling $t$ slightly only wiggles the output path slightly (this is shown in the picture since $f_{3/9} \approx f_{4/9}$, etc), but without formulas for $f_0$, $f_1$, and the homotopy $H_t$, there's no way to actually make this precise.

That said, there's an "easy" way that one can make this (and other pictures like it) precise using the fact that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is convex: use the **Linear Homotopy**.

> If we have two paths $p_0, p_1 : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ so that $p_0(0) = p_1(0)$ and >$p_0(1) = p_1(1)$, then they're *always* homotopic. Here's how:
>
> $$H_t(x) \triangleq (1-t) p_0(x) + t p_1(x)$$

That is, the point at position $x$ along $p_0$ moves in a straight line to the point at position $x$ along $p_1$.

Again, it's impossible to know for certain, since the two curves in your image don't have actual formulas associated with them, but this is as good a guess as any for how this particular image can be made "formal".

As for gaining some intuition working with homotopies, you might take some curves that you explicitly parametrize, and see what the straight line homotopy does to them. You can make some very pretty visualizations in [sage](https://sagemath.org), for instance, and maybe even [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/) if you're dedicated enough.

We can also take a moment to explain "why this works" (where by "this", I assume you mean the definition of homotopy). This is probably something that you'll need to meditate on for yourself, but the idea is this:

Instead of viewing a homotopy $H_t(x)$ as a function $[0,1]^2 \to X$, view it as a function

$$H_t : [0,1] \to ([0,1] \to X)$$

that is, it takes $t$ to the *function* $x \mapsto H_t(x)$. If you're a programmer, you might have heard this called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Then $H$ is a path in $([0,1] \to X)$. That is, $H$ is a path *in the space of paths*. So it continuously moves us from $p_0$ to $p_1$ (points in the space of paths) in the same way that $p_1$ continuously moves us from $x_0$ to $x_1$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, it helped a lot! However, I have some follow-up questions and I'd appreciate if you could take time to answer them. 1) Can I even be certain that paths I draw in $\mathbf{R}^3$ are really paths? Such as $f_0$, how can I be certain that this is really a path? It is intuitive that it is, but is there certainty? 2) Why is your $H_t$ given by linear homotopy continuous? It may be obvious, but I think an explanation would help. 3) Why can I view $H_t$ as a function from $[0,1] \to [0,1] \to X$? Thank you in advance!

Comment: (1) A path is _defined_ to a be a continuous map from $[0,1]$ into your space. Again, any picture you draw will be a path as long as you don't lift your pencil from the page. Remember, the definition of continuity was chosen to agree with our intuition. (2) If it's not clear why $H_t(x)$ is continuous, working it out for yourself will be an instructive exercise. (3) I was intentionally slightly vague here. You can only view $H$ as a function $[0,1] \to [0,1] \to X$ for certain "nice" spaces $X$.  The relevant keywords to google are "compact-open topology" and "exponential object"